# How can I apply bootstrap to my whole django project?

Tags: django, bootstrap-4

I've been looking at a few guides on applying bootsrap to django, and I am as far as having a static file in the root of my site, containing the css and js files within bootstrap, but when it comes to linking the files I am having an issue.

So I am trying to link the stylesheet inside of my base.html file but am not sure how to format it as for some reason using {% %} inside of the href field is being interpreted as part of the directory. In one of the videos I have watched he links it like this[image]But I'm not really sure how to interpret this as trying to apply it to my own like so

`href = "{% static 'artForAll/css/bootstrap.css' %}`"

With the file structure for reference:

```
\AFA\src\artForAll\static\artForAll\css
```

I am given an error about a non existent file as it is taking the {%%} as part of the directory
[image: error]

My settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static"),
]
```

File structure(blue highlighted file is where BASE_DIR leads:

[image: directory]

Comment: Have you done `{% load static %}` ? Also you forgot to close `}`

Comment: yeah at the top of base.html

Comment: and yeah you're right but that unfortunately didn't fix the problem as I had it written correctly previously

Comment: But there's a `'` missing as well

Comment: also caught that a minute ago, still same issue

Comment: Just confirming, you have this exactly: `href = "{% static 'artForAll/css/bootstrap.css' %}"`

Comment: yeah just updated post for you with new code

Comment: Have you set `static` in your settings? What I mean is `STATIC_URL` and `STATICFILES_DIRS`

Comment: I have static_url and staticfiles_dirs in my settings, not just static, I assumed it was something built into django based on the tutorials.  Will update post again to make sure the 2 static variables are correct anyway

Comment: It tries to find the static files in `templates` That can't be right.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's because base.html is in templates so it starts there for some reason, not sure what I can do to change that though

Comment: What's in your `BASE_DIR`?

Comment: BASE_DIR is the root of the site, so where manage.py is I'll add the file structure to the post and where BASE_DIR leads

Comment: What happens if you open `localhost:8000/static/artForAll/css/bootstrap.css`

Comment: it worked and takes me to the css file

Comment: Phew! That means we're not insane! Excellent. Then your problem lies in Visual Studio Code. Can't help you there. But was fun debugging.

Comment: Yep, looks like you were right, my cmd was outputting some error with it too, but I refreshed the cache on the site after noticing it was trying to use an old line of code, and now it seems to work. Glad I got it working but man was that a waste of time